# Find similar Text in R

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I have file with one columns (lets call it myvalues). It contains generic text in them (example below). The First row has 3 Purchase orders in them, the second row has one Purchase order (the who test is Purchase order), the Row3 has 3 purchase orders in them, row4 is actually only one Purchase order. Is there a way i can parse this in R, my goal is to identify which row has real multiple Purchase orders (in this case Row1 and Row3). Visually i can figure that Row1 has 3 different PO's ,  Row# has 3 PO's and Row 4 even though seems to have 3 PO's is actually only 1.

```
Row1 => 123456 556613 456826
Row2 => My PO#124 is the last one
Row3 => ABC-123-XYZ DEF-789-JJJ LMQ-529-333
Row4 => PO1234A LD6975A SHIPPED
```

Comment: You would need to formalize the structure of a purchase order somehow. What sequence of letters/numbers can represent a purchase order?

Comment: To expand on @LAP's comment, your best bet is to write a regular expression (regex) to match the format of correct PO numbers. https://regex101.com will make learning regex much easier. It's a live regex debugger that will show you exactly what your regex is matching and why.

Comment: Regex is not possible, as there is no actual pattern, it is more like our brain would interprets ROW1 to have multiple PO's and ROW3 has multiple PO's. The PO's come from customers and there is no format as such. I am looking for  a text analyzer here to really break out similar (quasi) text.